# Can't convert factors to numeric in R

Tags: r

When a try to convert the factor, x, to a numeric in R, it gives me NAs introduced by coercion.

I've tried these, but they don't work.

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))

as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))

as.numeric(levels((x)[x]))
```

X looks like this:

```
[1] -0.761407420967365,-0.199385294325
Levels: -0.761407420967365,-0.199385294325
```

Comment: Your `x` looks like a single long string, so you have both `.`, `-` and `,` in your string.

Comment: Try using `destring()` from the underappreciated `taRifx` package. It's more robust at formatting characters. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/taRifx/versions/1.0.6/topics/destring

Comment: This works for me: `X <- unlist(strsplit(x, ",")) ; as.numeric(levels((X)[X]))`

Comment: When x is a factor with one element (a long string), this modification of ekstroem's code works for me: 
`x <- factor("-0.761407420967365,-0.199385294325")`;
`X <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ","))`;
`as.numeric(X)`